# Django: change app language programmatically (without /i18n/setlang/ view)

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

My situation is the following:

I'm developing a multi-language site and currently I use the Django view **/i18n/setlang/** to let user switch language from a dropdown menu, and all works fine… but now, I wish to set the language programmatically, specifically I have a form with a series of settings and, among these, there is a "favorite language" voice, once the user submit the form, my view saves the User model and theoretically after that it should set the application language using the saved preference, but it does not work. What I tried is:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate

activate(lang)
```

but the result is bizarre: the UI after the redirect is still in the old language, but the message of successful update (django messages framework) is displayed back in the expected language!

I've also checked the source code of the Django view: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/i18n.py

And I saw that they save the selected language in session if available (I have session activated), so I tried:

```
self.request.session['_language'] = form.cleaned_data['favouriteLanguage']
```

…but is not working, what should I do?

I'm using Django 1.6 and the django middleware I did install are the following:

```
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

ps: in both my tries, {{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }} in template prints the old language code :(

Comment: Did you try to set new language explicitly:
request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language() ?

Comment: yes, it's useless… and anyway I need to set the language permanently not only for the current view :/

Comment: do you use **i18n_patterns**?

Comment: no, but I'm gonna try them :P

Comment: Perhaps django selects language based on a factor that has higher priority. Once I had similar problem, when language was overriden by url prefix from **i18n_patterns**. Check the doc corresponding to your django version [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)

Comment: thank you, I solved and I'm using i18n_patterns… they are an amazing feature!! :)

Answer (score 2):

activate alone does not do the trick.

Check out django.views.i18n.set_language:

```
def set_language(request):
    """
    Redirect to a given url while setting the chosen language in the
    session or cookie. The url and the language code need to be
    specified in the request parameters.

    Since this view changes how the user will see the rest of the site, it must
    only be accessed as a POST request. If called as a GET request, it will
    redirect to the page in the request (the 'next' parameter) without changing
    any state.
    """
    next = request.REQUEST.get('next')
    if not is_safe_url(url=next, host=request.get_host()):
        next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        if not is_safe_url(url=next, host=request.get_host()):
            next = '/'
    response = http.HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lang_code = request.POST.get('language', None)
        if lang_code and check_for_language(lang_code):
            if hasattr(request, 'session'):
                request.session['django_language'] = lang_code
            else:
                response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang_code)
    return response
```

It has everything you need to do to set language in view programmatically. since you already have localemiddleware, then that view is all you need. But do not copy paste it just like that. Keep that activate in that view. I think you might need that one though :)

Comment: Honestly I don't understand your answer, I saw that code, as I wrote in my question… you are telling me to use that code and to add a call to activate() in my own view? If so, I tried that, but does not work

Comment: No im not telling you that. I am telling you that you need to do what that view does in additon to calling activate(language). You also need to do request.session['django_language'] = language and you need to do response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language).

Answer (score 2):

Solved!!! Thanks to Dmytriy Voloshyn which informed me about the magic **i18n_patterns** (I did not know them :P).

In order to obtain what I want, these are the steps I've done:

**[1] Set up i18n_patterns in my base urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', include('mysite.core.urls')),
    url(r'^foo/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),
    # ...
)
```

**[2] Write an utility class to change the path prefix:**

```
import re

from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.translation import check_for_language


class PathUtils(object):
LANGUAGE_PREFIX_REGEX = re.compile('^/[a-z]{2}/')

@classmethod
def __pathHasValidPrefix(cls, path):
    matches = cls.LANGUAGE_PREFIX_REGEX.findall(path)
    if not matches:
        return False
    return check_for_language(matches[0].strip('/'))


@classmethod
def replaceLanguagePrefix(cls, path, newPrefix):
    """
    Returns the original path string with the language prefix replaced by the given one.
    Returns the unmodified path if language prefix is not found or is invalid (the language is not
    available for the application).



    :param path: (str) url path
    :param newPrefix: (str) 2 chars language code (ie: "IT", "DE", "ES"...)
    :return: (str) Path with new prefix
    """
    path, newPrefix = force_text(path), force_text(newPrefix)
    if not check_for_language(newPrefix) or not cls.__pathHasValidPrefix(path):
        return path
    return cls.LANGUAGE_PREFIX_REGEX.sub('/{0}/'.format(newPrefix), path)
```

**[3] Use that class in my view after user preferences form submission:**

```
def form_valid(self, form):
     form.save()
     self.success_url = PathUtils.replaceLanguagePrefix(self.success_url, form.cleaned_data['locale'])
     return super(UserSettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**[4] Override the default LocaleMiddleware in order to read user preferences:**

```
from django.middleware.locale import LocaleMiddleware as BaseLocaleMiddleware
from django.utils.translation import activate


class LocaleMiddleware(BaseLocaleMiddleware):
"""
Override Django LocaleMiddleware in order to read user preferences.
"""

def __userHasLanguagePreference(self, request):
    return request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.locale


def __activateUserFavoriteLanguage(self, request):
    activate(request.user.locale)
    request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.user.locale


def process_request(self, request):
    if self.__userHasLanguagePreference(request):
        self.__activateUserFavoriteLanguage(request)
    else:
        super(LocaleMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
```

It is important to import middleware in the right order for this implementation, AuthenticationMiddleware MUST be imported before LocaleMiddleware, otherwise user would be missing in request (and accessing request.user will rise an exception!).

satisfaction++ (ops… in Python: satisfaction += 1)

UPDATE:

I simplified my approach in order to rely only on the custom LocaleMiddleware, this is the updated class:

```
from django.middleware.locale import LocaleMiddleware as BaseLocaleMiddleware
from django.utils.translation import get_language_from_path

from myapp.PathUtils import PathUtils


class LocaleMiddleware(BaseLocaleMiddleware):
    """
    Override Django LocaleMiddleware in order to read user preferences.
    """

    def __userHasLanguagePreference(self, request):
        return request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.locale


    def __honorUserLanguagePreference(self, request):
        preferred = request.user.locale
        language = get_language_from_path(request.path_info, supported=self._supported_languages)
        if language != preferred:
            request.path_info = PathUtils.replaceLanguagePrefix(request.path_info, preferred)


    def process_request(self, request):
        if self.__userHasLanguagePreference(request):
            self.__honorUserLanguagePreference(request)
        super(LocaleMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django has an excerpt about it in its documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language

> You may want to set the active language for the current session explicitly. Perhaps a user’s language preference is retrieved from another system, for example. You’ve already been introduced to django.utils.translation.activate(). That applies to the current thread only. To persist the language for the entire session in a cookie, set the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME cookie on the response:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
> from django.http import HttpResponse
> from django.utils import translation
> user_language = 'fr'
> translation.activate(user_language)
> response = HttpResponse(...)
> response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, user_language)
> ```

Note that important point for Django 3.0:

> Changed in Django 3.0:
>
> In older versions, you could set the language in the current session.

So there is no point in putting the language in session anymore (I have wasted my time doing so).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent post and it provided me a deep insite on how to properly implement it on my solution. However, with the new version of Django 3.0 + I need to make some modification.

I've used request.META.get("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE",
"en") in place of the request.locale. I also modified the private methods to make it more pythonic.

```py
class LocaleMiddleware(BaseLocaleMiddleware):
    """
    Override Django LocaleMiddleware in order to read user preferences.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def __user_has_language_preference(request):
        return request.user.is_authenticated and request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', "en")

    @staticmethod
    def __recognize_user_favorite_language(request):
        preferred = request.user.profile.user_language
        language = get_language_path(request.path_info)

        if language != preferred:
            request.path_info = PathUtils.replace_language_prefix(request.path_info, preferred)

    def process_request(self, request):
        if self.__user_has_language_preference(request):
            self.__recognize_user_favorite_language(request)

        super(LocaleMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
```

Then on the form.is_valid method I changed it to the language based on the context data obtained from the user's language preference saved on the user's model.

```py
self.success_url = PathUtils.replace_language_prefix(self.success_url, form.cleaned_data['user_language'])
```