# Django i18n without language prefix

Tags: django, internationalization

Django documentation dictates i18n_patterns to implement i18n.

I'm hoping to accomplish this without using language prefix.

[Django: change app language programmatically (without /i18n/setlang/ view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888444/django-change-app-language-programmatically-without-i18n-setlang-view)

This suggests something similar but I'd like to accomplish it using request session.

The user will be able to change language using GET request.

How do you implement MiddleWare and View to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Language prefixing is an optional future, just follow the rest of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set language via HTTP GET parameter try this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1948/